# How to check entity is already created?

Tags: 7, entities

I have the code that create entity named "Victory" in entity type, my problem is how to prevent user creates the entity with the same name again.

```
function commerce_services_store_create($data, $flatten_fields) {
  $storeName = $data['store_name'];
  $status = 1;


  $entityType = "fruit_store";       //entity type name Fruit Store                         
  $entity = entity_create($entityType, array('type' => "store")); //bundle store
  $entityWrapper= entity_metadata_wrapper($entityType,$entity);  // create entity named "Victory" 
  $entityWrapper->title->set($storeName);
  $entityWrapper->save();

  $store_id = $entityWrapper->id-> value();   
  if($store_id != null){
    $reply= (array('status' => $status,'result' =>"Your store name ". $storeName. " Store id is ". $store_id));
  }else{
    $status = 0;
    $result = "Can't create store.";
    $reply = $reply= array('status' => $status,'result' => $result);
  }

  return $reply;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like validating the user email in any system you check if its already exists or not, in your case we need to check that we have no entity with the same attribute value exists:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'Fruit_Store')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'store')
  // this is a condition for the entity field values
  ->fieldCondition('field_title', 'value', 'spotlight', '=');

$result = $query->execute();

if (!empty($result['Fruit_Store'])) {
  // entity already exsits.
}
else{
  // add new entity
}
```

you can find more information about EntityFieldQuery in this page:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the entity type with following:

entity_get_property_info($entity_type = NULL)

Reference:

http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21entity%21includes%21entity.property.inc/function/entity_get_property_info/7

Updated: Check the below example code for the existing entity

```
  try {
    // account for user entity exists error
    if (!($args['type'] == 'user' && $account = user_load_by_name($values['name']))) {
      $data = entity_property_values_create_entity($args['type'], $values);
    } else {
            $data = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $account);
    }
    return array('entity_created' => $data);
    }
catch (EntityMetadataWrapperException $e) {
    throw new RulesEvaluationException('Unable to create entity @type": ' . $e->getMessage(), array('@type' => $args['type']), $element);
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, that is for entity type, I mean entity, in my question entity_type is Fruit_Store, bundle is store, entity is Victory. I wouldn't let the user create Victory entity again, not entity_type. I just want to validate entity that is already created. Thanks

Comment: @SAWAUNG: check updated answer